# Read values from structured array of string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, search, filter

So basically I'm reading in lines from a text based file into an array. Each line = new array element. This text based file is automatically generated so structure is consistent between file to file. I would like to read values out of the array element. Below is an example of a line I want to read.

```
;Basic settings: Layer height: 0.2 Walls: 0.8 Fill: 20
```

So I would like to extract the Layer height value, Walls value and fill value from (for example) array element 4 (gline[4]).

What would be the best way to do this? I'm using VS2012 programming in C#. These numbers are all positive numbers, but other than that can be any size.

This is the code I have tried, but I'm not able to get "0.2" or "0.8" to be picked up as a number.

```
Variables.gcodeLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Variables.FilePath);

var numbers = Regex.Split(Variables.gcodeLines[3], @"^\d+(.\d+){0,1}$").Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray();
MessageBox.Show("" + numbers[0] + " " + numbers[1]);
```

If you do provide sample code, can you please explain the basic principals behind it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?  If you haven't tried anything yet, what do you *think* would be the best approach?

Comment: I have used a for loop plus the contains() method to find the line in the array I want to work with. I have tried getting Regex.Match() to work, but to no avail. Would this be the best way?

Comment: Do you have any control over the input? There are ways it could be structured to be much easier to parse in the .NET side.

Comment: The file is created by a software package outputting gcode to the file. Its structured and has to be universally compatible. I recently tried using the regex.split() function, but I'm having issues with it recognizing 0.2 as a number. This looks to be just a filter issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the regular expression you want is `@"\d+(\.\d?)?"`. And you don't want to split on that, you want the matches.

So what you want is:

```
var re = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d?)?");
var matches = re.Matches(Variables.gcodeLines[3]);
var numbers = matches.Cast<Match>().ToArray();
```

First, you want `Matches` rather than `Split` because `Split` will give you the things separated by the numbers. That's why you use `Split` to split out a comma-separated list: it gives you everything but the commas.

`Matches`, on the other hand, gives you a `MatchCollection` that contains the numbers.

The regular expression, `@"\d+(\.\d?)?"` says:

```
a string of digits
optionally followed by a period and 0 or 1 digits
```

You have to escape the period because it's a special character (match any character) in the regex world.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've never had it explained like that. So for 0.25 I would use @"\d+(\.\d\d?)?" ?

Comment: @user3684557: If you want to match a number with up to two decimal places, you would write `@"\d+(\.\d{0,2})?"`. That is, one or more digits optionally followed by a period and 0, 1, or 2 digits. So "1." would be valid, as would be "1.1" and "1.12".